# Why Roo does not generate views?

Tags: spring-roo

In my Roo project I want to add form that allows user to change password. I want the form to have 3 fields: current/new/repeat password, so I cannot use my entity I use to persist account data due to fields and their validation mismatch.

It appears that I can use any class as a form to scaffold controller (via `--backingType` of `web mvc scaffold`), but for some reason it does not work for my custom form field.

My project is configured like like:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.test --projectName temp --java 6 --packaging JAR
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
web mvc setup
```

Account entity:

```
entity jpa --class com.test.domain.Account
field string --fieldName name
field string --fieldName password
```

Change password form:

```
class --class ~.form.ChangePasswordForm
field string --fieldName currentPassword
field string --fieldName newPassword
field string --fieldName repeatPassword
```

This generates controller and views as expected:

```
web mvc scaffold --class com.test.web.AccountController --backingType ~.domain.Account
```

This creates only empty controller and no views at all:

```
web mvc scaffold --class com.test.web.ChangePasswordFormController --backingType ~.form.ChangePasswordForm
```

So, my question is why Roo does not scaffold controller/views in the second case and what is the best way to handle this scenation with Roo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web mvc scaffold` is designed to scaffold CRUD controllers for domain models that use Roo's JPA integration.

In order to implement this CRUD Roo needs to know how to persist your model objects.

In other words you do need to use class annotated with `@RooJpaEntity` as a `--backingType`.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe try an another similar tool in Github named  [Sloth -  https://github.com/coolcooldee/sloth](https://github.com/coolcooldee/sloth) !

It has several features：

```
1.Generate Model–View–Controller Code
2.Generate CRUD  Code
3.Generate API DOC
4.Provide Many Kinds Of Data Access With JDBC ：Mybatis、JOOQ、Spring JDBC
```